# How to access vector<vector<Point>> contours in opencv like matrix element?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, contour

My problem is I do not know how to access `vector <vector <Point>>` contour (this is 2D like matrix on OpenCV)

I want to do this. If Mat element does not consists in contours area I want to suppress that matrix elements. In order to do this I need to know contours element too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my situation was so urgent, I would ask my question more carefully.

If I try hard to understand your question, you basically want to consider a contour in pixel level. In order to do that, you should draw the contour into a blank matrix with drawContour. And then compare two matrices or match a pixel in that matrix in case you want pixel by pixel.

Comment: Ok, you got my question very well. The contours are from RGB and I want to compare this contours pixel location with another depth image corresponding pixel location . , in order to suppress some pixel of depth image.I am using kinect sensor, Also I cannot exactly find the object  contours, in my case contours are not exact. How to     
find exact contours?

Answer (score 11):

You need a for loop for both the first and the second vector. Something Like this:

```
vector< vector<Point> > contours;

for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++) // run until j < contours[i].size();
    {
        cout << contours[i][j] << endl; //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replied. But I do not understand your post for loop?int i;i=0;i<contours.size() ???

Comment: it worked . I also have an question my contours are not exact as I expected findContours(img1,rgbcontours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0) );
do you have a trick for this?

Comment: Just a quick comment where if you want to access the actual `x` and `y` coordinates, the `cv::Point` structure has `x` and `y` members, so `int x = contours[i][j].x;` and `int y = contours[i][j].y;` will access the members respectively. BTW, I upvoted a while ago.  Wanted to add this comment and to also thank you. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all points rather than just the edge points, you can use `drawContours(....,thickness=CV_FILLED)` to dump this contour on a dummy Mat, then you can obtain those points by scanning the dummy Mat.

Comment: if you are compiling from the latest opencv repo, then it should be FILLED instead of CV_FILLED